Proving, using Dedekind cuts, that $C(0)$ is an additive identity for addition on cuts.
My source is Franck Ayres' Modern Algebra. The author states the fact under discussion (Chapter 7, "Real numbers") but does not provide a proof.

My question is about the second part of the proof,  ($\Leftarrow$) direction.


Let $C$ be a Dedekind cut.  $C$ can be written as $C(r) = \{ x \mid x < r \text{ for some } r \in \mathbb{Q} \}$.  The goal is to prove that: $C + C(0) = C$.  I first prove that  $C + C(0)$ is included in  $C$.
Suppose $x$ belongs to $C + C(0) = \{ c + c_0 \mid c \in C \text{ and } c_0 \in C(0) \}$.
Because $x$ belongs to $C + C(0)$, $x = c + c_0$ for some $c \in C$  and some $c_0 \in C(0)$.
We have: $c < r$ and $c_0 < 0$. Therefore, $c+c_0 < r + 0 = r$ implying that $x \in C$.  So, for all $x$, $x \in C + C(0)$ implies $x \in C$.
Second part of the proof : $\Leftarrow$ direction.
I now want to show that: $C \subseteq C+C(0)$. I first consider the case in which $C$ is a negative cut, meaning that $C \subseteq C(0)$.
Suppose that $x \in C$. Because multiplication by a positive rational  preserves order, $x < r$ implies $x/4 < r$. Set $c = x/4$, we have $c < r$ and $c \in C$. Also, set $c_0 = c = x/4$. This implies $c_0 \in C$ and consequently $c_0 \in C(0)$. It follows that $$c+c_0= 2c = 2(2(x/4))=x,$$ meaning that $x$ can be written as the sum of two elements of $C$ and $C(0)$ as desired.

My problem is that I cannot find a trick to write $x$ as $ x = c+c_0$
( with $c\in C $ and $c_0\in C(0)$) in the second case, namely, when $C$
is not included in $C(0)$, but, the other way around, when
$C(0)\subseteq C$.

Or, does the problem lie in my decision to distinguish 2 cases?

Putting such large sections of text into math mode has made your post nearly illegible.  Yours is not the first I've seen do this though, so I'm curious: did you actually put in the effort to manually type that out, or is it the output of some what-you-see-is-what-you-get program converting it to latex?

My " prompt" : " * I now want to show that  :* C inclued in C+C(0).// I first consider the case in which C is a negative cut , meaning that  * C subsetequal C(0) Suppose that* x in C. Because multiplication by a positive real preserves order,  x < r implies  x/4  <r. Set  c = x/4, we have : c<r* and c  in C.  Also, set c_0 =c = x/4. This implies : c_0 in C and  consequently * c_0 in C(0). * It follows that *  c+c_0= 2c = 2(x/4)=x * meaning that x can be written as the sum of two elements of ( respectively * C and C(0 as desired.

I aimed  at displaying a neat mathematical text with the natural language parts coded with the \text command. So I've provided ChatGPT with the above  text with additional instructions , and I confess the result is not top level

I have re-written your post without using some much text in math mode.  I have not fixed some of your errors.  For instance, $$C(r) = {x : x < r \text{ for some } r \in \mathbb{Q}$$ is not sensible for how $r$ is bound both to $C(r)$ and inside the set notation.  I might guess you meant $$C \text{ can be written as } C(r) = {x \in \mathbb{Q} : x < r} \text{ for some } r \in \mathbb{Q}$$ but while this is notationally sensible, it's false in general.  Please compare the text as it currently stands with your source material.

(i) Do not use chatGPT for anything other than personal amusement when you are bored and want to waste time with a chatbot.  (ii) That is a terrible use of Mathjax/Latex.

The first sentence is very weird. I suspect that the assertion is that if $r$ is a rational then the set $C(r)={x\in\mathbb{Q}\mid x\lt r}$ is a Dedekind cut, but not that every Dedekind cut can be written that way.

@Brian Moering.  Sincere thanks for having taken time to rewrite my post.

@Arturo Magidin. Thanks for correcting my mistake as to the ( im)possibility of writing  any cut  as $C(r)$ for some rational $r$. I need to make a new post asking how a cut in $Q$ can fail to be of this form.

@VinceVickler The cut ${r\in\mathbb{Q}\mid r\lt 0\text{ or }(r\geq 0\text{ and }r^2\leq 2)}$ is famously not of that form.

@Arturo Magidin. Thanks for making all that clear.

The proof that $C \subseteq C + C(0)$ is fairly direct, having nothing to do with $C \subseteq C(0)$ or $C(0) \subseteq C$.

Suppose $x \in C$.  Then [since $C \subset \mathbb{Q}$ is a cut] $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and there is some $r > x$ such that $r \in C$ (so in particular, $r \in \mathbb{Q}$).
It follows that $x-r < 0$ and $x-r \in \mathbb{Q}$, so $x-r \in C(0)$.
Therefore,
$$x = r + (x-r) \in C + C(0)$$

Suppose $ x\in C(r)$, $r\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $x<r$, and we have that:
$$x<r \implies x -\frac x2 < r - \frac r2 \implies x < r + \frac{x-r}{2}$$
But our hypothesis says that $x-r <0$, so $\frac{x-r}{2} \in C(0)$.

Does your answer take care of the case in which C  ( in the statement : C+C(0) = C) is not a rational cut? I failed to consider this case in my reasoning above. It has been pointed out in the comments
